# Unsubscribing from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat system within my Ionic app that is displayed within a modal window. Within the modal window I have the code below. It seems that after using the app for a while it becomes a bit sluggish.

I suspect that it's because I should be unsubscribing from Firebase when I close the modal window. In other words, it seems like a new subscription is being made each time I click the button to open the modal. Is this the case? If so, what should I do? I don't see an unsubscribe option in the docs?

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    firebase.database().ref('chatrooms/'+this.roomkey+'/chats').limitToLast(30).on('value', resp => {

        this.chats = [];
        this.chats = snapshotToArray(resp);
        this.content.scrollTo(0, 999999, 200);

    });
}
```

I have tried the following to call `off` but unsure if it is the correct approach? I have put this within `ionViewDidLeave()`

```
firebase.database().ref('chatrooms/'+this.roomkey+'/chats').limitToLast(30).off('value');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should always remove any listeners on a database reference when that listener is no longer needed.  Otherwise, that listener will continue to receive snapshots when data changes.

To remove a listener, use the [off()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off) method on the same reference that you used to call [on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on).  Pass it the callback function that you passed on on().  Please also read the documentation for [detatching listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners).

Comment: Doug, thank you very much for the reply. I have edited my question, is this what you're suggesting? Basically copy the code used for on but replace on with off?

Comment: You don't need the listener anymore, just `off('value')`.

Comment: Thank you - just edited the question again. Like that?

Comment: no, "with the same callback function" aka off("value", someCB)