# React Native Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code which listen to changes in the Realtime database when new child added.

```
mUserRef = firebase.database().ref("Messages").child(conversation);
mUserRef.on("child_added", snapshot => {
    const message = {
        key: snapshot.key,
        ...snapshot.val()
    };
    this.onReceive(message);
});
```

and this code will be triggered when received new child added to the database ref

```
let cy = this;
        firebase
        .database()
        .ref("LastMessages")
        .child(key)
        .once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
            //...some code
        });
```

the problem is i can't unsubscribe off the realtime listener when i use **componentWillUnmount**

***Code for unsubscribe***

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ready: false,
      messages: []
    };
  }
  _isMounted = false;


componentDidMount = async () => {
    this._isMounted = true;
}

  async retriveMessages(conversation) {
    let cy = this;

    cy.setState({
      ready: true
    });
    let mUserRef = null;
    if (this._isMounted) {
      mUserRef = firebase
        .database()
        .ref("Messages")
        .child(conversation);

      mUserRef.on("child_added", snapshot => {
        const message = {
          key: snapshot.key,
          ...snapshot.val()
        };
        this.onReceive(message);
      });
    } else {
      mUserRef.child(conversation).off("child_added");
    }
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
```

Solutions i tried:

[Unsubscribing from Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011828/unsubscribing-from-firebase-realtime-database)

[componentwillunmount to unsubscribe from firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905711/componentwillunmount-to-unsubscribe-from-firestore)

[how to remove firebase database listener...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453389/how-to-remove-firebase-database-listener-when-ref-path-is-no-longer-available)

[How to stop Firebase Listener when i pass to another screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485590/how-to-stop-firebase-listener-when-i-pass-to-another-screen)

Comment: why cant you unsubscribe?

Comment: @PeterHaddad i have no idea what's wrong, i tried using `this._isMounted` and trigger it to false after i navigate away from the page and i got same problem, and used `mUserRef.off('child_added')` when `componenwillunmount`  and still same issue

Comment: add the code for unsubscription

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`componentWillUnmount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount):

> `componentWillUnmount()` is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any subscriptions that were created in componentDidMount().

Therefore do the following:

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
    mUserRef.off("child_added");
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
```

Comment: amazing, i have one last question need your advice on, i stored `state.mUserRef` in state and when component unmount i called `this.state.mUserRef.off("child_added");` do you think this is good idea and will keep the app scaled ?